# how to calculate two select result in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two select cluse :

one :

```
select sum(value) from tblcust where year=2013
```

> its return : 12.34 or 0 or null

two:

```
select sum(value) from tblcust where year=2014
```

> ite return 0 or grate than or null

I want calculate this :

```
((12.34-0)*100)/(12.34+0)
```

how to do this ?

I searched on google but cant find any result.

**updated :I change -(mines) to `/` devide**

```
((12.34-0)*100)/(12.34+0)
```

AND GETTING THIS ERROR :

> Divide by zero error encountered.

BECUASE ONE OF CASE RETURN ZERO

Comment: Question is unclear. Kindly clarify your question by providing sample data and expected result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this:

```
SELECT
    ((t.Sum2013-t.Sum2014)*100)-(t.Sum2013+t.Sum2014)
FROM
(
    SELECT
        ISNULL(sum(CASE WHEN year=2013 THEN value ELSE 0 END),0) as Sum2013,
        ISNULL(sum(CASE WHEN year=2014 THEN value ELSE 0 END),0) as Sum2014
    from 
        tblcust
) AS t
```

**Update**

The original requirement was that with `-`. If you are chaining the `-` to `/`. Then you need to do an additional check. The problem is this:

```
SELECT 1/0
```

Which is a basic mathematical exception. This will raise the exception:

> Divide by zero error encountered.

So in the statement you have to decide what you should happened if you divide by 0. One suggestion with is not mathematical correct is this:

```
SELECT
    ((t.Sum2013-t.Sum2014)*100)/ 
    (
        CASE 
            WHEN (t.Sum2013+t.Sum2014)=0 
            THEN 1 
            ELSE (t.Sum2013+t.Sum2014) 
        END
    )
FROM
(
    SELECT
        ISNULL(sum(CASE WHEN year=2013 THEN value ELSE 0 END),0) as Sum2013,
        ISNULL(sum(CASE WHEN year=2014 THEN value ELSE 0 END),0) as Sum2014
    from 
        tblcust
) AS t
```

Comment: when change - to / in  `((t.Sum2013-t.Sum2014)*100)-(t.Sum2013+t.Sum2014)` igetting  error , because one of case return zero .

Comment: how to use '-' in isnull instead of zero . when i change it , igetting error .

Comment: I want change `0` with `-` in isnull . but when i chage it I getting error . beacuse `-` can not calculate (+,-,/) . how to can Do it ? thanks mr

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for something like below:

```
select (sum(case when year = 2013 then value else 0 end) -
       sum(case when year = 2014 then value else 0 end)
        ) * 100
        +
        (sum(case when year = 2013 then value else 0 end) +
       sum(case when year = 2014 then value else 0 end))
from tblcust
```